# Is this question about replacing bananas on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Recently there was this question about replacing bananas being asked: [How to replace bananas in Europe?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2128/how-to-replace-bananas-in-europe#)

At first I thought this is clearly off-topic since there is no direct connection to Vegetarianism or Veganism, but after looking at it from different angles I can see why the question might be asked here - OP is vegan and is looking for a local vegan replacement of a certain food.

Do you think questions like these are in scope?

Comment: I think part of the question has some merit. Assuming vegans are concerned about carbon footprint overall, it's helpful to ask what are the most sustainable crops for a specific region. But the question itself is poorly worded -- the submitter seems to be asking for a replacement in their personal diet, not a replacement across all of Europe.

Comment: The question actually doesn't specify a vegan replacement (including a tag doesn't actually count), just "a fruit." I am leaning towards not a V&V question, but pondering where I might migrate it rather than outright close it.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the rule of thumb is: **is it primarily vegetarians or vegans interested in banana alternatives?**

- Veg*ns certainly eat bananas, but so do a *lot* of people, and for similar reasons ("delivers enough energy before or during sport activities").
- Veg*ns are often interested in the environmental impact of their food choices (question seeks a lower CO2 footprint), but again, many other people do as well.
- We know this particular user is vegetarian based on other questions and participation, but that isn't a determining factor (for an extreme/silly example, I can't post Python coding questions on Vegetarianism.SE just because of what foods I don't eat)

I lean towards "this is not on topic for our site," but I would like to migrate it rather than close outright. I'm interested in additional community feedback, though.